# windows 2016 kubectl.exe :No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I've started learning kubernetes using docker in windows server 2016. I've already tested using minikube in my local machine successfully. but this time i want to start it through docker. but unfortunately it was failed with below error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> install-kubectl.ps1 -Downloadlocation $HOME/.kube
==>Getting download link from  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kub
ectl/
==>analyzing Downloadlink
==>starting Download from https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/relea
se/v1.13.0/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe using Bitstransfer
==>starting 'C:\Users\Siva_Sankara_Rao_Bac\.kube\kubectl.exe version'
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"13", GitVersion:"v1.13.0", GitComm
it:"ddf47ac13c1a9483ea035a79cd7c10005ff21a6d", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2
018-12-03T21:04:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd6
4"}
kubectl.exe : Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: 
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
At C:\Users\Siva_Sankara_Rao_Bac\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Scripts\install-kub
ectl.ps1:47 char:1
+ .$Downloadfile version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unable to conne...ely refused it.: 
   String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

i've tried to figured it out but my knowledge not  able get it even from google .tried many ways as instructed in different websites. but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

> kubectl.exe : Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080:
>   connectex:  No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it.

You see this error because when you run `kubectl version`, it shows you client version (kubectl binary) first and then version of your Kubernetes cluster. It tries to connect to the cluster using *current context* in the `.kube/config`.

It looks like you don't have a cluster or you don't have it configured in `$HOME/.kube/config`

Without correct configuration `kubectl` uses default values like `localhost:8080` and as you obviously don't have `kube-apiserver` running on that `IPaddress:port`, kubectl fails to get the Kubernetes cluster version and print the connection error message.

If you activated **docker-for-desktop cluster** after using **minikube**, you may need to switch `kubectl` context in the docker icon context menu.

**The bottom line**: There is nothing wrong with `kubectl` or its installation on your computer. To fix the issue, you need to create a cluster and put the correct connection configuration in the `kubectl` config file.